# Keyboard-free mouse gestures for XMonad

Tags: mouseevent, gesture, xmonad

I'm setting up mouse gestures in my xmonad.hs, and I'd like to avoid using a modMask modifier to get keyboard-free gestures. Problem is, there are cases (e.g. empty gesture, just a simple click) where I'd like to let the mouse event go through to the application under the cursor, but I haven't found a way to do that in XMonad. Without that, if i add `((0, button3), mouseGesture gestures)`, i completely lose the "application-specific" functionality of `button3`.

I was thinking that, if the events cannot be easily forwarded, perhaps a new one can be created and dispatched. I thought about using `spawn "xdotool click 3"` but it doesn't seem to work. Has anybody ever tried something similar? Otherwise, I'd need a mouse with at least 4 buttons, since most apps actively use three...

Comment: Did you make any further progress on this @BruceBerry?

Answer (score 0):

To get xdotool to forward your mouse clicks, you need to make sure that it targets the correct window using the `--window` parameter. For example, if your window id is 79693135, then `xdotool click --window 79693135 3` does exactly what you want.

The following basic `xmonad.hs` illustrates how to do this in order to get keyboardless mouse gestures working properly:

```
import XMonad
import qualified XMonad.Actions.CycleWS as Workspace
import XMonad.Actions.MouseGestures ( mouseGesture, Direction2D(..) )
import qualified XMonad.Util.EZConfig as EZ
import XMonad.Util.Run ( safeSpawn )

import qualified Data.Map as Map

mouseGestureButton :: Button
mouseGestureButton = button3 -- right click

sendMouseClickToWindow :: Window -> X ()
sendMouseClickToWindow win = 
    safeSpawn 
        "xdotool" ["click", "--window", show win, show mouseGestureButton]

myMouseGestures :: [([Direction2D], Window -> X ())]
myMouseGestures =
    [ ([R], const Workspace.nextWS) -- move to the next workspace
    , ([L], const Workspace.prevWS) -- move to the previous workspace
    , ([], sendMouseClickToWindow)
    ]

addMouseGestures :: XConfig a -> XConfig a
addMouseGestures = 
    flip EZ.additionalMouseBindings 
      [((0, mouseGestureButton), mouseGesture $ Map.fromList myMouseGestures)]

main = xmonad $ addMouseGestures def
```

N.B.: It's not a good idea to use button 1 for this, because that will interfere with selecting text and other mouse-dragging functionality normally used with button 1. So using button 3 (as the OP did) is definitely the right idea.

Comment: Update: it turns out that some applications (such as Eclipse and Xfce system tray applets) don't respond to mouse clicks sent through xdotool. Pressing alt or shift while right-clicking works, though.

Comment: Did you make any further progress on this @Matt_M?

Comment: Nope. That's the best I have, I'm afraid.